# Upgrading from Sitecore.Search to Sitecore.ContentSearch

Tags: content-search, lucene

I am currently upgrading a Sitecore environment from 8.0 update-2 to 8.2 update-4, but am running into some problems with our custom websearch module.
This module uses the old Sitecore.Search implementation to create a Lucene index and search in it. But since 8.2 this is obsolete and I can't find the right way to upgrade this module.
I used the Sitecore.Search.ISearchContext to create a custom SearchContext, but I can't find anything similar in the new ContentSearch implementation.
The full code is found here: https://github.com/efocus-nl/sitecorewebsearch/blob/develop/src/FixedSearchContext.cs
Has anybody already been able to fix something similar as this issue?

Kind regards,
Guido

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I didn't have a search context, but another solution full of old termQuery, terms, etc.
Instead of rewriting the whole logic to the new LINQ implementation, we implemented a ".toLinq()" method to our main objects, and then did something like this:

A method to be able to use our objects transparently with linq:

```
 public static IQueryable<Result> Where(this IQueryable<Result> query, IMyObject parameter)
    {
        var pq = PredicateBuilder.True<Result>();
        query = query.Where(parameter.ToLinq(pq));
        return query;
    }
```

The we can use our objects like this:

```
var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex(indexName);
            using (var context = index.CreateSearchContext())
            {
                var q = context.GetQueryable<Result>();
                q = q.Where(myObject);
                var results = q.GetResults<Result>();
            }
```

Comment: Hi Vincent, thanks for your answer! Very usefull and clean code example of yours :)